# Ionic doesnt display image loaded from backend

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have to request a binary image from a server, but I need extra headers and authorization. Thus I can only do this on the backend. After I receive the image using ionic native HTTP, I’ve tried to display the image several times, but none worked.

1) I tried setting the binary data to a field like this:

```
this.unit.img(this.unitInfo.logo).then( (r) => {
  this.logo = r.data;
}
```

And on html:

```
  <ion-img [src]="logo"></ion-img>
```

2) I also tried converting the img to a base64 img, like this:

```
 this.unit.img(this.unitInfo.logo).then( (r) => {
      var imageData = btoa(r.data);
      this.logo = "data:image/png;base64,"+imageData
```

And also:

```
  <ion-img [src]="logo"></ion-img>
```

To display the image, but none of these works :frowning:

Dont know if this is useful, but this is the code used to fetch the image:

```
make_get_img(path, options){
    let headers = Object.assign({
        'Accept': '*/*',
        'Content-Type': '*/*'
        }, options.headers || {})

    if(this.token){
        headers = Object.assign(headers, {
            'token': this.token
        })
    }

    let url = this.getUrlWithParams(path, options.urlParams)


    return this.http.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }, headers);
}
```

I tested the string on other sites, and I get a message saying the conversion was wrong.

I dont know how to fix this.
Please help.

**EDIT**

I Also tried converting the img like this:

```
    var u8 = new Uint8Array(r.data);
    console.log(u8)

    var b64encoded = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, u8));
    var mimetype="image/png"; // or whatever your image mime type is

    this.logo = "data:"+mimetype+";base64,"+b64encoded;
    this.logo =  this.logo.replace(new RegExp(' ', 'g'), '+');
```

Also tried:

```
  var imageData = btoa(r.data);

  let objectURL = 'data:image/png;base64,' + imageData;
  this.logo = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(objectURL);


  console.log(this.logo)
```

[image]

Comment: try simple `img` tag. `ion-img` tag have some issues.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tried that, but same result :( Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
this.unit.img(this.unitInfo.logo).then( (r) => {
      var imageData = btoa(r.data);
      this.logo = "data:image/png;base64,"+imageData
 this.logo =  this.logo.replace(new RegExp(’ ', ‘g’), ‘+’);
```

it all the “+” in your base64 encoded image are replaced by a blank character …so if you have just to put them back... There is a bug...

this fixed the bug for me hope it will work for you too...

> since you are getting error while displaying the image you can use
>   DomSanitizer... in also in your ts file add

ts

```
    import { DomSanitizer } from "@angular/platform-browser";
     constructor(
    private DomSanitizer: DomSanitizer
  ) {}
```

html

```
<img
        [src]="DomSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(base64Image)"
        *ngIf="base64Image"
        alt="Ionic File"
        width="300"
      />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'm pretty sure it will help others, but didnt solve for me :( Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is [`URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) that can be used to create a URL representing the Observable of [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) returned in `make_get_image`.

In your code, you have accessed `data` in the blob but this has `undefined` value as the return value of `make_get_image` is an observable of Blob.

You should *subscribe to* / resolve blob from the Observable and create a URL to it. For example,

```js
this.unit.img(this.unitInfo.logo).then((b: Blob) => {
  this.logo = URL.createObjectURL(b);
});
```

Note that you may or may not need to [set the width and height properties](https://stackoverflow-questions-57412128.stackblitz.io) of `<ion-image>` or in style properties of CSS class selector applied in the tag.

Comment: Didnt test it yet, will give feedback asap, thank you anyhow =]